# In azure logic apps is there any validity for SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic apps is there any validity or expiration time for SAS token, as it I'll be in the URL if the expiration time is there then URL will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sharing the URL with other parties, you can **generate URLs with specific keys and expiration dates as needed**. You can then seamlessly roll keys, or ensure access to fire an app is restricted to a certain time span.

You can specify an expiration date for a URL through the logic apps REST API:

```
POST 
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/triggers/{triggerName}/listCallbackUrl?api-version=2016-06-01
```

In the body, include the property `NotAfter` as a JSON date string, which returns a [callback URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowversions/listcallbackurl) that is only valid until the NotAfter date and time.

[image]
To add an expiration date to the trigger of the Logic App, open the `LogicApp.json` in code view in Visual Studio. Locate the triggers section and add the following to it inside the `schema` section:

```
"NotAfter": "2018-06-01T11:00:00.511Z"
```

Adjust the date and time to your needs. The triggers section will now look like below:

```
"triggers": {
          "manual": {
            "type": "Request",
            "kind": "Http",
            "inputs": {
              "schema": {
                "NotAfter": "2018-06-01T11:00:00.511Z",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "text": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "text"
                ]
              },
              "method": "POST"
            }
          }
        },
```

For more details, refer to this article to [Callback URLs with an expiration date](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/07/26/securing-your-azure-logic-apps-part-1-secure-access-to-the-trigger/)

Comment: Thank you, one more question by default does it have an unlimited expiration time

Comment: Default has no expiration time. You could “reset access keys” which would invalidate previous SAS URLs but without that should be valid for lifetime if app